# Scipy's RectBivariateSpline returns wrong value?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Trying to interpolate data from a regular input grid, and came across this in the documentation for `scipy.interpolate.interp2d`:

> See also RectBivariateSpline Much faster 2D interpolation if your
>   input data is on a grid

So I tried using `scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline` instead of `interp2d`. Docs for both functions seem very similar, so I expected this to produce similar results:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import RectBivariateSpline, interp2d

from .constants import data


x_coords = y_coords = np.arange(data.shape[0])  # Square array
interp_fun = interp2d(x_coords, y_coords, data)
bivar_fun = RectBivariateSpline(x_coords, y_coords, data)

data[250, 60]  # 76.1451873779
interp_fun(60, 250)  # 76.14518738
bivar_fun(60, 250, grid=False)  # 345.24444
```

Am I calling this wrong? I have no idea why the interpolation based on `RectBivariateSpline` is so far off?

I did suspect that maybe `RectBivariateSpline` operates on a cartesian grid and inverted the y-Axis of input data, but still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Right, just before submitting this I thought I should try calling `bivar_fun(y, x)` instead of `bivar_fun(x, y)` and things suddenly work:

```
data[250, 60]  # 76.1451873779
interp_fun(60, 250)  # 76.14518738
bivar_fun(250, 60, grid=False)  # [ 76.14518738]
```

Still not quite sure why, because the first arguments to `interp_fun` and `bivar_fun` should be the same:

> `RectBivariateSpline.__call__(x, y, mth=None, dx=0, dy=0, grid=True)`

[RectBivariateSpline Docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline.__call__.html#scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline.__call__)

> `interp2d.__call__(x, y, dx=0, dy=0)`

[Interp2d Docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.__call__.html#scipy.interpolate.interp2d.__call__)

There's also a related issue on Github: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/3164